# Coloring points in a cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I have a question that relates to the Widom-Rowlinson model of statistical physics.  Take a cycle on $n$ vertices.  How many ways are there to color the $n$ vertices with the colors $\{\text{Red, Yellow, Blue}\}$ with the only restriction being that Red vertices cannot be next to Blue vertices?  I'd like an explicit formula, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the  matrix $A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 1\cr}$.
The number of ways to colour $\{0,1,\ldots, n\}$ subject to your restriction with 
$0$ coloured $i$ and $n$ coloured $j$ is $(A^n)_{ij}$  So the number of ways to colour your cycle is $\text{Tr}(A^n)$.  Now $A$ has eigenvalues $1$, $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$, so the answer is $1 + (1+\sqrt{2})^n + (1-\sqrt{2})^n$.

Comment: This is a very helpful perspective --- thanks!  Typo in the last line of $A$, I assume --- row should be $0, 1, 1$?